# How to configure CUPS put jobs in queue with status HELD(4)?

Tags: linux, debian, cups

I can't find this property in `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` or `/etc/cups/printers.conf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CUPS' command line client for each job individually like so:

```
 lp -d printer -o job-hold-until=indefinite jobfile
```

You can also use the `lpoptions` tool to set this as a default, for ***all*** jobs sent by the same user. This will then even apply for jobs you send from GUI applications:

```
 lpoptions -p printer -o job-hold-until=indefinite
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? Maybe it should be `job-hold-until-default=indefinite`.